# Is there an easy way to export multiple arrays in a proper Table?

Tags: php

Current i decoded this from my json

```
Array
(
    [summonerId] => 19936953
    [modifyDate] => 1394886787000
    [champions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 76
                    [name] => Nidalee
                    [stats] => Array
                        (
                            [totalSessionsPlayed] => 1
                            [totalSessionsLost] => 1
                            [totalSessionsWon] => 0
                            [totalChampionKills] => 1
                            [totalDamageDealt] => 22680
                            [totalDamageTaken] => 12406
                            [mostChampionKillsPerSession] => 1
                            [totalMinionKills] => 14
                            [totalDoubleKills] => 0
                            [totalTripleKills] => 0
                            [totalQuadraKills] => 0
                            [totalPentaKills] => 0
                            [totalUnrealKills] => 0
                            [totalDeathsPerSession] => 6
                            [totalGoldEarned] => 5496
                            [mostSpellsCast] => 0
                            [totalTurretsKilled] => 0
                            [totalPhysicalDamageDealt] => 5232
                            [totalMagicDamageDealt] => 17447
                            [totalFirstBlood] => 0
                            [totalAssists] => 3
                            [maxChampionsKilled] => 1
                            [maxNumDeaths] => 6
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 36
                    [name] => DrMundo
                    [stats] => Array
                        (
                            [totalSessionsPlayed] => 1
                            [totalSessionsLost] => 1
                            [totalSessionsWon] => 0
                            [totalChampionKills] => 1
                            [totalDamageDealt] => 89170
                            [totalDamageTaken] => 20817
                            [mostChampionKillsPerSession] => 1
                            [totalMinionKills] => 152
                            [totalDoubleKills] => 0
                            [totalTripleKills] => 0
                            [totalQuadraKills] => 0
                            [totalPentaKills] => 0
                            [totalUnrealKills] => 0
                            [totalDeathsPerSession] => 3
                            [totalGoldEarned] => 8401
                            [mostSpellsCast] => 0
                            [totalTurretsKilled] => 0
                            [totalPhysicalDamageDealt] => 24456
                            [totalMagicDamageDealt] => 64544
                            [totalFirstBlood] => 0
                            [totalAssists] => 2
                            [maxChampionsKilled] => 1
                            [maxNumDeaths] => 3
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 115
                    [name] => Ziggs
                    [stats] => Array
                        (
                            [totalSessionsPlayed] => 2
                            [totalSessionsLost] => 2
                            [totalSessionsWon] => 0
                            [totalChampionKills] => 0
                            [totalDamageDealt] => 108574
                            [totalDamageTaken] => 12076
                            [mostChampionKillsPerSession] => 0
                            [totalMinionKills] => 187
                            [totalDoubleKills] => 0
                            [totalTripleKills] => 0
                            [totalQuadraKills] => 0
                            [totalPentaKills] => 0
                            [totalUnrealKills] => 0
                            [totalDeathsPerSession] => 3
                            [totalGoldEarned] => 9138
                            [mostSpellsCast] => 0
                            [totalTurretsKilled] => 0
                            [totalPhysicalDamageDealt] => 9926
                            [totalMagicDamageDealt] => 98510
                            [totalFirstBlood] => 0
                            [totalAssists] => 2
                            [maxChampionsKilled] => 0
                            [maxNumDeaths] => 2
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 254
                    [name] => Vi
                    [stats] => Array
                        (
                            [totalSessionsPlayed] => 4
                            [totalSessionsLost] => 3
                            [totalSessionsWon] => 1
                            [totalChampionKills] => 10
                            [totalDamageDealt] => 360858
                            [totalDamageTaken] => 63341
                            [mostChampionKillsPerSession] => 5
                            [totalMinionKills] => 127
                            [totalDoubleKills] => 0
                            [totalTripleKills] => 0
                            [totalQuadraKills] => 0
                            [totalPentaKills] => 0
                            [totalUnrealKills] => 0
                            [totalDeathsPerSession] => 10
                            [totalGoldEarned] => 30065
                            [mostSpellsCast] => 0
                            [totalTurretsKilled] => 0
                            [totalPhysicalDamageDealt] => 314488
                            [totalMagicDamageDealt] => 2988
                            [totalFirstBlood] => 0
                            [totalAssists] => 12
                            [maxChampionsKilled] => 5
                            [maxNumDeaths] => 5
                        )

                )



                )
```

Now what i wanted to know is is there an easy way to display all variables like Totalsessionslost totalsessionsplayed and do it for every array?

Im trying to make a sort of website like lolking.net by using the Riot Games APi hopefully you guys can help me out

Greetings

Comment: A basic loop can do this.

Comment: Im not that experienced with arrays yet as im just a starting coder so i really have no clue

Answer (score 1):

consider having a single array:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

getting this to print would be as easy as this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $array.length; $i++) {
    print $array[$i]; //here I select the i-value in array, so if i = 2 the output will be 3
}
```

multiple arrays within eachother work the same, only its a loop within a loop

```
for($i......) {
    print "first array value: ". $i;
    for($o = 0; $o < $secondarray.length; $o++) {
        print "second array value: ". $o;
    }
}
```

Use this with the data structure you have got present.

If you need this in a table, you will have to add html tags in the print statements. Do keep your variables outside of the string (quotes) though.

ie:

```
for($summonerIndex = 0; $summonerIndex < $mainArray.length; $summonerIndex++) {
   $championArray = $mainArray[$i];
    for($championIndex = 0; $championIndex < $championArray.length; $championIndex) {
        $statsArray = $championArray[$o];
        for($statsIndex = 0; $statsIndex < $statsArray.length; $statsIndex++) {
             print "Value of statsarray: ". $statsArray[$statsIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** this is untested and may contain errors.

[More info on PHP.NET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

[Also more info here on multiple loops](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/2/6/13)

Comment: Well the API returns the arrays like that so ill have to use multiple

Answer (score 0):

There is a class "Set" in CakePHP framework http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html
Check out Set::extract method.

Comment: But there wasn't tag for CakePHP. This question needs plain PHP answer.

Comment: Yep, but this class can be easily extracted from CakePHP and included into any project.